# Check which rows with each word in a string are capitalised and space separated

Tags: r, regex, grepl

I have a column with string of values as shown below

```
a=["iam best in the world" "you are awesome" ,"Iam Good"]
```

and I need to check which rows of each word in string are lower case and separated by space.

I know how to convert those to Upper and space separated but i need to find which rows are lower case & space separated.

I have tried using

```
grepl("\\b([a-z])\\s([a-z])\\b",aa, perl =  TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try using `grepl` with the pattern `\b[a-z]+(?:\\s+[a-z]+)*\b`:

```
matches = a[grepl("\\b[a-z]+(?:\\s+[a-z]+)*\\b", a$some_col), ]
matches

  v1              some_col
1  1 iam best in the world
2  2       you are awesome
```

**Data:**

```
a <- data.frame(v1=c(1:3),
                some_col=c("iam best in the world", "you are awesome", "Iam Good"))
```

The regex pattern used matches an all-lowercase word, followed by a space and another all-lowercase word, the latter repeated zero or more times.  Note that we place word boundaries around the pattern to ensure that we don't get false flag matches from a word beginning with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- c("iam best in the word ", "you are awesome", "Iam Good")
```

Here I did something different, first I separeted by space then I check if is lower case. So, the output is a list for each phrase with only the lower case words split by space.

```
sapply(strsplit(x, " "), function(x) {
  x[grepl("^[a-z]", x)]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

We can convert the column to lower-case and compare with actual value. Using @Tim's data

```
a[tolower(a$some_col) == a$some_col, ]

#  v1              some_col
#1  1 iam best in the world
#2  2       you are awesome
```

If we also need to check for space, we could add another condition with `grepl`

```
a[tolower(a$some_col) == a$some_col & grepl("\\s+", a$some_col), ]
```

Comment: hehehe... but then again, Great minds think alike ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to use `stri_trans_totitle` from `stringi` package,

```
a[!!!stringi::stri_trans_totitle(as.character(a$some_col)) == a$some_col,]

#  v1              some_col
#1  1 iam best in the world
#2  2       you are awesome
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
a %>%
   filter(tolower(some_col) == some_col)
#   v1              some_col
#1  1 iam best in the world
#2  2       you are awesome
```